# ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. Such as Array

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

This is the error I'm facing rightnow.
(ERROR Error: NG02200: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables, such as Arrays. Did you mean to use the keyvalue pipe?)

```js
export class StudentDataComponent {

  newdata:any;

  // list = [];

  constructor (private userAPIData:StudentDataService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userAPIData.getdata().subscribe(res =>{
      this.newdata= res;
      console.log(this.newdata)
  })
  }
  
}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let user of newdata;">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: newdata is not an array, ngFor only operates on things it can iterate over such as an array which is what i think you want your data to be in this scenario. Proper typing (not using any) would help you here to avoid errors like this.

Comment: Proper typing like what? without using any.

Comment: Use a custom `type` or an `interface` instead of `any` to specify the type of a variable. For example, if you have an array of string, you can simply do `public myVar: string[] = [];`.

Comment: @MuhammadAnas please share the console.log output in the question!

Comment: @NarenMurali hello there,

https://pasteboard.co/YdvBngKFG4Vx.png

you can see the error with the above link.

Comment: change `this.newdata= res;` to `this.newdata= res.users;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

newdata is an object datastructure, which is incompatible with *ngFor instead go for the users array inside it, please change the code to below!

```
export class StudentDataComponent {

  newdata:any = { users: [] };

  // list = [];

  constructor (private userAPIData:StudentDataService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userAPIData.getdata().subscribe(res =>{
      this.newdata= res;
      console.log(this.newdata)
  })
```

}

```
<tr *ngFor="let user of newdata.users;">
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{user.id}}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error in the console for the users, but the data is fetched and showing in frontend.

this is the error now.

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'users

Comment: @MuhammadAnas updated my answer!

Comment: it worked thankyou bro

Comment: @MuhammadAnas You're welcome!